# How Do You Show All Characters In Echo On In Batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm having a problem where I can't get all characters (especially special characters) to show when I try to echo them

```
echo 1234567890q!w@e#r$t%y^u&io()pa;s/d.f,ghjklzxcvb nmQAZXSWEDCVFRTGBNHYUJMKIOLP
```

When using this code in batch, it doesn't show the characters (especially the special characters) but instead say "This program is not recognizable as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.". The reason to why this is saying this is because the lines have special characters but how do I show the special characters in echo on? Thanks people.

Comment: Your first `SET` will not work, as you don't setting any value to a variable. What do you mean with `ECHO ON`? Did you place `ECHO ON` before your code or do you try to output it via `ECHO %CHARSET%`?

Comment: Oh my apologies I meant to just copy and past this.                               "echo 1234567890q!w@e#r$t%y^u&i*o()pa;s/d.f,ghjklzxcvb nmQAZXSWEDCVFRTGBNHYUJMKIOLP" not "SET "1234567890q!w@e#r$t%y^u&i*o()pa;s/d.f,ghjklzxcvbnmQAZXSWEDCVFRTGBNHYUJMKIOLP"
SET "CHARSET=1234567890q!w@e#r$t%y^u&i*o()pa;s/d.f,ghjklzxcvbnmQAZXSWEDCVFRTGBNHYUJMKIOLP"

Comment: I apologise for the mistake also can you replace the two lines of code with   "echo 1234567890q!w@e#r$t%y^u&io()pa;s/d.f,ghjklzxcvb nmQAZXSWEDCVFRTGBNHYUJMKIOLP" please thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Neither of those lines results in that particular error message when I test them from the command line (although the first results in "Environment variable 123456etc. not defined").  You have properly quoted your "variable=value" pair, and there is no problem setting CHARSET to that value.

I suspect the problem is that when you `echo %charset%` the `&` is being evaluated as a command separator, and evaluating the string thereafter as a new command.  Try retrieving the value of `CHARSET` in the delayed expansion style.

```
set "charset=1234567890q!w@e#r$t%%y^u&io()pa;s/d.f,ghjklzxcvb nmQAZXSWEDCVFRTGBNHYUJMKIOLP"
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
echo !charset!
endlocal
```

By the way, if you want to include a literal percent, you should do it double (`%%`).

Comment: Faster than me and you write the same I'm currently writing +1

Comment: He may need to [escape](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php) several characters to get it to work like he wants.

Comment: @BaconBits No, only the `%` needs to be doubled, the rest is safe, as it's inside quotes

Comment: @jeb I'm assuming it's an example.  He, or someone else in the future, very well may want `|`, `<`, or `>`, or find that `^` doesn't work as he expects.

Comment: @BaconBits But in quotes you must not escape `|<>&` or even the caret itself. Only the percent sign isn't affected by quotes

Comment: @jeb I encourage you to try `set "var1=test<"` followed by `set "var2=test^<"` followed by `echo %var1%` and `echo %var2%`.

Comment: @BaconBits Actually, I just tested, and retrieving by delayed expansion removes the need to double-pump the caret.

Comment: `var2` contains 6 characters `test^<` instead of 5. It solves the problem to `echo` the content with percent expansion, but you could/should solve it much better with delayed expansion, like `echo !var1!`. The content should be _clean_ so other functions can work with it like stringLen or substring

Comment: @jeb You guys are missing the point.  The problem here was "how do I echo a string to the screen with special characters in it?"  Someone *could* write a batch script that way I did.  They *may* want to know how to escape a special character in a standard environment variable so that it echos to the screen.  Delayedexpansion may not be available if they only control the variable definition and not the script. String length may not matter. Escaping the character is not *wrong*.  It's just a *different solution* that someone may want to use.

Comment: Yes, it's a different solution, but a bad technic. As a simple `set /p var2=[Enter text]` will break your script or do you expect that the user will add the proper escaping? But that is only my private attitude :-)